# Parse iTunes top 100

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml, itunes

I want to get the following information from the iTunes top 100 RSS but am having issues with the below.

```
function itunes(){
$itunes_feed = "https://itunes.apple.com/au/rss/topsongs/limit=100/explicit=true/xml";
$itunes_feed = file_get_contents($itunes_feed);
$itunes_feed = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $itunes_feed);
$itunes_xml = new SimpleXMLElement($itunes_feed);
$itunes_entry = $itunes_xml->entry;

    foreach($itunes_entry as $entry){
        // Get the value of the entry ID, by using the 'im' namespace within the <id> attribute
        $entry_id['im'] = $entry->id->attributes('im', TRUE);
        echo $entry_id['im']['id']."<br>";
        //echo $entry_id['artist']."<br>";
    }
}
```

I can get the id from `<id im:id="783656917">`

However I can not get the following

```
<im:artist href="https://itunes.apple.com/au/artist/pharrell-williams/id14934728?uo=2">Pharrell Williams</im:artist>
```

I want to get `Pharrell Williams` i have tried 
`$entry->id->attributes->im[artist]
$entry_id['artist']`
and even `$entry_id->artist`

But no matter what I do I cannot get it to give me the artist name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the object to string

```
$value = (string)($entry->imartist);
```

Comment: sorry just checked the xml, this is correct now. please try again with above line.

Comment: how is this not an answer to the question? the question is "i want to get Pharrel Williams" and this code will just do that.

Comment: I noticed that I did not need the (string) part to use this code I just used $entry->imartist